# Can an Azure Logic app which is under consumption plan call the the azure function which is under app service plan with VNet integration

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-app-service-plans

Can an Azure Logic app which is under consumption plan call the the azure function which is under app service plan  with VNet integration.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can utilize Azure functions in logic apps with VNet integration, however, you must take into consideration that you can only use HTTP triggered functions.

Below is my logic app flow that triggers azure function app service plan with VNet integration.

[image]

**In my Function app:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply swetha. But I'm getting error "Forbidden". The web app you have attempted to reach has blocked your access ...

Comment: If your function app authorization level is set to function then the Logic App HTTP request must include the key for use when calling the function app also. Or you need to setup your Logic App's identity to have access to the function app. Several options are available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions?tabs=consumption).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Depending on the size of your project, I'd recommend considering use of an APIM resource in between the Logic App and the Function App for abstraction and reduction of fragility. Not to mention APIM giving you the ability to support customer level api-keys with different rate limits, etc. in the future.